# OnClickListener Null Object Reference

Tags: java, android

I know this issue has been put out there 100 times, but nothing I've seen solves this. I have a button in a layout called fragment_main which is shown to another layout: activity_main. That button opens a fragment called AddEditFragment, which allows users to add info to a form that then spits it into a recyclerview(fragment_main) that is shown in MainActivity.

I have both layouts due to having a navigation drawer in a linearlayout in activity_main and the recyclerview and button in fragment_main constraintlayout. However I have onDelete/Edit/Save methods already up and going in MainActivity, so it only makes sense to me to put the button onClickListener there as well. Except since the button isn't in the main layout, activity_main, I get a fatal null object exception.

Even though fragment_main is shown in activity_main is there a way around this so the OnClick method can be put into MainActivity for a button in a linked layout?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerViewAdapter.OnVehicleClickListener,
                                                                FragmentAddEdit.OnSaveClicked,
                                                                NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private DrawerLayout drawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        // Launcher view
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new FragmentMainActivity()).commit();
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_garage);
        }

        Button button_add = findViewById(R.id.button_add);


        button_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AddEditRequest(null);
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_garage:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new FragmentMainActivity()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_history:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new FragmentHistory()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_upcoming:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new FragmentUpcoming()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_about:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new FragmentAbout()).commit();
                break;
        }

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveClicked() {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment AddEditFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if (AddEditFragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .remove(AddEditFragment)
                    .commit();
        }

    }

    public void onEditClick(@NonNull Vehicle vehicle) {
        AddEditRequest(vehicle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeleteClick(@NonNull Vehicle vehicle) {

    }

    private void AddEditRequest(Vehicle vehicle) {

        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, FragmentAddEdit.class);
        if (vehicle != null) {
            detailIntent.putExtra(Vehicle.class.getSimpleName(), vehicle);
            startActivity(detailIntent);
        }


    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".com.carupkeep.MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".com.carupkeep.FragmentMainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/no_vehicles"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/no_vehicle_message"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_add"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:drawableTint="@color/colorAdd"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:text="@string/addVehicle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vehicle_list" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/vehicle_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/no_vehicles"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

***UPDATE***

I got close but still feel so far. I've given up on trying to keep it in MainActivity and put it in FragmentMainAcitivity as suggested. Except now I have 2 can't resolve errors. The first being on view in view.findViewById button initialization AND on fragment_container in the callback method. Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

```
public class FragmentMainActivity extends Fragment {

    Button button_add = view.findViewById(R.id.button_add);

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        button_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                Fragment AddEditFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(fragment_container, AddEditFragment).commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

easier way to do it is to put

```
onClick="AddEditRequestView"
```

in your fragment_main.xml

so it will be

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button_add"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:drawableTint="@color/colorAdd"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:text="@string/addVehicle"
    android:onClick="AddEditRequestView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vehicle_list" />
```

and in your MainActivity.java

add this method

```
public void AddEditRequestView(View viewc){
AddEditRequest(null);
}
```

and delete these code from your activity

```
 Button button_add = findViewById(R.id.button_add);


        button_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AddEditRequest(null);
            }
        });
```

Comment: `public void AddEditRequest(View viewc){
AddEditRequest(null);
}` Stackoverflow!